# Cannot convert system.generic.list anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class I want to populate from a Linq query, but I am using a sub select statement to slightly alter the properties of the list.  I have a class it should fit into but it refuses to go in.  I am wondering if there is a way I can get these results to fit into the list as I defined it rather than a generic anonymous type.

```
public class SCADA_DATA_Truncated
        {
            public string acode { get; set; }
            public string LOCCODE { get; set; }
            public Nullable<System.DateTime> COLDATE { get; set; }
            public string RESULT { get; set; }
            public string analyte { get; set; }

            
        }
```

And here is where I am attempting to populate the data:

```
List<SCADA_DATA_Truncated> dataResults = (SCADA_DATA_Truncated)(from b in a2Entity.SCADA_DATA
                                           where DbFunctions.TruncateTime(b.COLDATE) >= dateCheck1 && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(b.COLDATE) <= dateCheck2
                                           && whereInAcode.Contains(b.acode) && whereInLoc.Contains(b.LOCCODE)
                                           select new
                                           {
                                               COLDATE = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(b.COLDATE),
                                               acode = b.acode,
                                               LOCCODE = b.LOCCODE,
                                               RESULT = b.RESULT,
                                               analyte = b.analyte
                                           }
                                       ).ToList();
```

Comment: Do you mean to do `select new SCADA_DATA_Truncated { ... }`? And remove the cast.

Comment: You need to put `SCADA_DATA_Truncated` after `select new`; no need for cast etc, can also `var dataResults`. If some of the things in the curly brackets aren't directly assignable to the types of properties in a SCADA_DATA_Truncated then you can convert them in place

Comment: Also maybe consider NOT truncating the time off in the where; manipulating table data in a where clause is usually a recipe for disaster, performance wise, as it can preclude the use of indexes. Better to just search a range eg `b.COLDATE >= startDate && b.COLDATE < midnightOnTheDayAfterEndDate` If you want eg everything that happened in Jan then you search `datecol >= '2021-01-01' and datecol < '2021-02-01'` not  `cast(datecol as date) >= '2021-01-01' and cast(datecol as date) <= '2021-01-31'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an anonymous type:

```
select new 
{
     COLDATE = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(b.COLDATE),
           acode = b.acode,
           LOCCODE = b.LOCCODE,
           RESULT = b.RESULT,
           analyte = b.analyte
}
```

The runtime has no idea how to convert it to your class

Why not changing it to

```
select new SCADA_DATA_Truncated
{
      COLDATE = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(b.COLDATE),
               acode = b.acode,
               LOCCODE = b.LOCCODE,
               RESULT = b.RESULT,
               analyte = b.analyte
}
```

You can then remove the explicit cast altogether